# Remove/Clear select option value in a freeform pro edit form

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am having a weird issue in a Freeform Pro edit form.
I'm using Freeform Pro v.4.2.5 and EE 2.11.2

I think I'm missing something obvious.
In my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n16y42um/3/), when Radio Option 1 is clicked , the two drop down menu fields are required.
When Radio Option 2 is clicked, the two drop down menus are hidden and their values, if any were selected, are removed.

This works fine.

My problem occurs when I edit a record.  If I had clicked Radio Option 1 and then two options from the select menus; if I go back and edit the record and choose Radio Option 2, while the select options are removed in the form, they are not deleted in the database.

Any ideas what I am missing?

I thought the code below removed the value from a select menu but it only saves the removed value from textfields.

```
$('#state_2').val("");
```

I also tried the code blow but it did not work either.

```
$('#country_2').prop( "selected", false );
```

Any help is appreciated, even if to let me know I'm missing something super obvious!
Thanks
Peter T

Answer (score 0):

I have avague recollection of hiding fields in forms not being updated. Try editing your forms with the non-required fields visible.

If that doesn't work then I vaguely recall submitting forms in EE with empty fields does not update the dB. Try putting in irrelevant/false content ie. none. You can then search those fields for content = 'NOT none'.